# Access Local Domain Name Website as API server in WAMP

Tags: wamp, virtualhost, hosts

I have two local Domain which work fine, however, the otherA domain is the API server that the otherB domain consumes API. The problem is it can't access the otherA domain, and returns network error something like

```
 option 1

 let apiserver = 'http://localserverA.local'
 axios.get(`${apiserver}/apicall`).....
 catch( ---> return network error
```

But this works

```
 option 2

 let apiserver = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
 axios.get(`${apiserver}/apicall`).....
 returns 200 ok
```

The problem with option 2 is to run php built in server which not a good idea because some set up in databases requires domain local host to access its data.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localserverA.local
    ServerAlias localserverA.local
    DocumentRoot C:/projects/r/projects/A/web
    <Directory "C:/projects/r/projects/A/web">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from All
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Allow from ::1

        #FallbackResource /app.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can even ping my domain name, it works well in browser but got network error when endpoint called via javascript. Works well in production
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

> This may help you:

Go to directory *(from where your landing page load, if you have laravel project you need to go to public directory)* to your project in command promt and fire command.

```
php -S <ip addresss>: <any port no>
```

*like this*

```
php -S 192.168.1.62:4200
```

Now you can access that project using `192.168.1.62:4200`

Comment: Yes its really work but as I said, the site has requirements that only domain names allowed to access data in databases

Comment: that you need to configure your server configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file. Add next line:

```
127.0.0.1 localserverA.local
```

Comment: actually its working fine, what I need is to call some routes e.g /apicall from inside from another local domain with same wamp server like let = http://localserverA.local/apicall as the url for an ajax call, but it return network error